# How to remove usage tip in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij,there is `usage` button.
How can I remove it? I try to google it but can't find any solution

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hide `Usages` by disabling it in the IDE settings

⌘ + , (macOS), or Ctrl + Alt + S (Windows/Linux)

Then navigate to:

`Editor > Inlay Hints > Code Vision > Usages`.

and untick the checkbox

Comment: where is Editor?

Comment: In the Settings dialog. Alternative, just press shift twice and type "Inlay Hints". It will take you to the correct place.